# Is automatic widget install still not possible in Android?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

Can I install/add widgets during app installation or from within the app? (With User persmission, if possible)

Found an [old, answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957190/add-android-widget-on-app-install). Is this still not possible in Nov'16?

Comment: Widgets are meant to be an optional addition, at a place the user chooses. It makes no sense to automatically add them

Comment: Sidenote: this is not worth a new question. Just post a comment on the other one

Comment: Yes I know. But I could just let them choose the position...

Comment: @TimCastelijns how would others get to know??

Comment: They could read it

Comment: Oh! didn't even think of that... btw I left a comment to you on some random post. Do reply. And thanks for downvoting and not answering my question...

Comment: I am not notified of comments on posts I have not participated in. And thanks for assuming I downvoted your post, but your crystal ball is broken. It was not me

Comment: Ha! didn't know that either and my bad if that was not you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I install/add widgets during app installation or from within the app?

No.

As Android users know, there are many home screen implementations for Android. Across the thousands of device models there are hundreds of different pre-installed home screen implementations. And there are hundreds, if not thousands, of additional home screen implementations that the user can download and install from places like the Play Store.

None of these home screens have to support app widgets.

As such, Google did not implement an API to ask the home screen to install an app widget, let alone implement an API to *force* the home screen to install an app widget.

It is possible that some home screen implementations expose their own API for this, though I am not aware of any that do.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working on something where by default widgets could have solved a lot of problems. Guess, will have to think of something else...